# How to describe the orientation of an object?

Tags: phrase-request

[image]

I want to know how to instruct when a component needs to be attached to a car in a manner shown in the drawing above. My examples are as follows:

> Example 1: This component needs to be attached so that the green
>   colored end faces the front side of a vehicle.
>
> Example 2: This component needs to be attached so that the green
>   colored end is on the front side of a vehicle.

Comment: My only comment is that in English we do not refer to the front or rear of any vehicle as a 'side'. The front end or the rear end, or the hood/bonnet, or the trunk/boot can be used as well. The 'sides' are driver's side or passenger side -- though of course that may change by country of manufacture and /or usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This component must be attached oriented lengthwise in the direction of travel, with the green colored end toward the front. See diagram.

**This component must be attached** - this is more forceful than "needs to be", and it puts the requirement on the assembler, not the part - **oriented lengthwise in the direction of travel,** - with it's long axis aligned parallel with the long axis of the vehicle - **with the green colored end toward the front.** - in that manner. **See diagram.** - an accompanying diagram is always helpful in assisting the assembler in understanding the exact requirements.

Comment: Please [edit] to include some explanation of why this is a better choice than the examples. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](//meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.

Comment: CollenV - Thank you SO MUCH for this helpful link! Your answer to JR's question was excellent and helped me better understand where you're coming from (and what you and other moderators expect). I wish that our "help" section and tour linked to those posts. I feel it is very difficult for relative newcomers to learn what is expected of them. "Meta" is still mostly a mystery to me, and I have no clue where to go to find out more about how to use it more effectively. Thank you (as always) for your help. I realize we didn't get off on the best footing, but that is changing (at least for me).